# about auto -code folding blocks of comments in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, comments, code-folding

I'm new to PyCharm tool and trying to figure out the rule about auto-generated code-folding blocks of comments in PyCharm (2020.2.1, Community Edition Build PC#202.6948.78).

[Screenshot of my code: How can I show the code blocker in (A) instead of (B)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYMNp.png)

In the screenshot, the code blocker appears in (B) which does not help organizing code view. I'd like it to appear in (A).

For this, I tried:

1. changing number of "#" in different areas, but failed.
2. added another line of numerous "#"s above line 11: code folding appeared between line 10 and 11
3. chose line 12 and 13 and pressed Ctrl+".": This worked, but doing this every time would be bothersome.

Would anyone please provide me with some rule about when the comment folding starts and ends so that I simply follow the rule in my coding and set the default code-folding setting to reduce the visible part of my source code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options:

1. Just use `#%%` or `# In[]` for dividing python code into different sections;
2. Use the following code to make you code folding and show necessary content introduction:

```py
#<editor-fold desc="The content to show">
print('Hello World')
#</editor-fold>
```

For folding code, you could use `Code - Folding - Collapse All`. You could also use shortcut which is showing in the menu which is `Command Shift -` for macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Firstly, your answer No. 2 worked! Regarding No. 1, I found  "#%%" is supported by Professional version only while I'm using Community version and couldn't find a comment about "# In []". I tried with the following code:


##%% section 1
print (11)

##%% section 2
print (12)

# In [section 3]
print (21)

# In [section 4]
print (22)

#<editor-fold desc="section 5">
print (3)
#</editor-fold>

Additionally, while searching "#%%", I found there's a plugin making a code section by using ##, but it didn't do anything about folding

Comment: Glad to hear the second one worked. Sorry for the first method. I am using pro version. The first method worked for spyder before I started to use pycharm pro. Although it is not working for CE version, FYI, it is `#%%` with one star instead of `##%%`, also `# In[]` with space between `#` and `I`, without space between `n` and `[` instead of `# In []`.

Comment: I tried putting in different number of spaces but failed. Anyway, I found number of # does not affect closing of the No. 2, i.e., #############</editor-fold> works and only the description in "desc='description'" appears when collapsing the fold. This seems good enough for me. Thank you.